# Programmable prefetch/preload javascript with webpack ES6 import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, prefetch

In a large sized React SPA, I want some code chunks to be loaded when user open/using specific screen/feature.
Many our react components are lazy loaded with `const Component=React.lazy(() => import('./lazyCode'))`

I'd like to fetch-on-render and improve the UX delay.
Due to the size and complexity of the SPA, I do not want to load any of them too early.

e.g. I want to preload next react component (and it's dependency) while the "next" is dynamic and conditional based on user input.

Webpack support ES6 [import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './path/to/LoginModal.js');](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules) but however, it doesn't come with an API. Actually it is unclear when the prefetch will be triggered.

I can program a `import(pathToJs[i])` chain, but that does not work with `<link prefetch>` network priority in browser.

Webpack doesn't provide an API to get the actual URL to load, so I cannot do `<link prefetch>` myself either.

Is there any code pattern we could do for a managed spitted chunk lazy load?

Comment: Define user input. Organize your app so the lazy dynamic chunks are within separate directories and then use a dynamic `import(/* webpackPrefetch */)` for the modules in the app areas related to the "user input".

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to `react-loadable` for your purpose. It provides a preload API, and here's how it works.

In fact, if you want to preload, you can `execute an asynchronous import` anywhere if you need it, like this:

```js
export function loadable(factory) {
  const Component = React.lazy(factory);
  Component.preload = factory;
  return Component;
}

// usage
const PageAComponent = loadable(() => import('./PageA.tsx'))

// some where
<button onMouseEnter={()=> {PageAComponent.preload()
}} />
```

As for `Prefetch` in Webpack, its principle is to pre-insert chunk into the HTML document in the form of HTML link tags, which cannot be dynamically controlled.